# Bing Maps search defaults to Lancaster

Tags: bing-maps

I don't know if anyone have noticed this, when requesting from Bing maps REST service for some locations, or if the query was not well formed, the response from Bing maps gives the coordinates of Lancaster, Lancashire, as if it was defaulting to this location...

try this request and check the coordinates, it should yield the coordinates of "Bethnal Green, London - East", instead it is "Lancaster, Lancashire":

http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?locality=Bethnal+Green+&adminDistrict=%22London+-+East%22&countryRegion=UK&o=xml&key=BING_MAPS_KEY

Any info about this and how to stop it is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening is that the geocoder isn't understanding your lower level address information so it moves up through the address until it finds something. In this case it is returning a coordinate for the center of the UK. This just happens to be near Lancaster, Lancashire. If you look at the Name or address property of the result you will be able to see this pretty clearly. Also, since you are working with the REST services take a look at these tips and tricks: http://www.bing.com/blogs/site_blogs/b/maps/archive/2013/02/14/bing-maps-rest-service-tips-amp-tricks.aspx

Comment: I contacted Bing support and this is the exact response I got from them ... thanks mate

Comment: That's maybe because Ricky's is doing support among others in Europe. :)

Comment: This has been a fairly common support request that the Bing Maps support team and myself have come across over the years. Either that or someone on the support team found this post and copied and pasted it.